# Multiarch on Debian 9 breaks my system

Tags: debian, package-management, steam

I have a fresh, brand new installation of Debian 9.

After installation was completed, I installed the NVIDIA proprietary driver and everything worked fine.

The problem started when I tried to install Steam, because out of the box, it doesn't work on Debian 64 bit; I have to install some packages like:

```
apt install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
```

Which only works with:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

The problem is after that package is installed, because now I have some broken dependencies and I cannot use `apt` correctly, LibreOffice and Nvidia are uninstalled.

At the end, my whole system is broken and the only way for me to fix it is with a new fresh installation.

I have also tried `aptitude` and the problem is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately such problems are hard to solve using SO: they typically require you to cite the swaths of log output `apt`/`aptitude` produce, and then play Q&A session with folks who understand them. So I'd recommend to post a message to the [`debian-users` mailing list instead](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained on the official documentation debian : [Steam runtime issues](https://wiki.debian.org/Steam#Troubleshooting).

> Steam **ships with its own versions of some libraries** (the "Steam Runtime") in an attempt to emulate the Ubuntu 12.04 environment in later versions of Ubuntu.
>
> However, some core libraries included in the Steam Runtime will often **conflict with the newer versions of other libraries included in Debian** (such as drivers, and specifically the open-source ATI driver).

To solve the problem :

> remove offending files from Steam Runtime

```
# rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
# rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
# rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
# rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
# rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
# rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0
```

Restart your system.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Gdebi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gdebi).

`gdebi` installs a `.deb` package and its dependencies. To use it run:

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

You can install `gdebi` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

See [`man gdebi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gdebi) for a full list of options.

`gdebi` is the command line equivalent to the graphical tool of the same name , the command for the graphical tool is `gdebi-gtk` and has similar functionality:

[image: gdebi]

Comment: I'm gonna try it, but the question is why do I have this problem, why apt or aptitude uninstall bunch of programs

Comment: You're basically proposing to use a specific GUI front-end to do what `# dpkg -i path/to/a/package.deb` does; that does not address the stated problem in any way.

Comment: `gdebi` could help to fix broken dependencies (this means solving the problem), check [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me).